# Apache POI: Force celldata type to be NO formula?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Adding pure text from a different source, i noticed Apache POI (3.17) automatically assumes a String starting with `=` is interpreted as a formula. This is usually fine, but how can i make sure that in this special case, the cell is **NOT** a formula?

I assumed after adding the String starting with `=`, i can just tell Apache POI the type is `CellType.STRING`:

```
cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
```

But this does not yield the expected result, the String is still read as a formula in the output .xlsx file (using LibreOffice). Currently, i'm checking if each added String starts with a `=` and replace it with `'=` but i would much prefer to avoid all those checks. Example how i currently handle it:

```
strOut = in_CSV(i,j);
strOut = strOut.startsWith("=") ? "'"+strOut : strOut;
```

So is there a better way to make sure my output is NOT a forumula in Apache POI?

Comment: No there is not another approach because it is **not** `apache poi` what makes strings starting with `=` to formulas. `Excel` is doing that **after** opening the file. But you should not prefixing an apostrophe. Instead do using a `CellStyle` having [setQuotePrefixed(true)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setQuotePrefixed-boolean-).

Comment: Perfect, just tested it and it works as intended. Thats exactly what i had in mind, using a POI function instead of checking and modifying the Strings myself, i was just looking in the wrong class. Thank you, if you want to add it as a solution i would certainly accept.

Comment: Rechecked it worked, just doesn't add the `'` which threw me off

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interpreting a String starting with `=` as a formula is done by `Excel` or `Calc` **after** opening the file. So `apache poi` can only prevent this if it uses the same markers in the file which `Excel` would use to mark strings starting with `=` as **not** a formula. This mark is called "**quote prefix**". It looks like an apostrophe in editor bar of `Excel` but is not really part of the cell content.

So simply putting an apostrophe in front of the cell content will be the wrong approach. This works while importing text (`CSV`) in `Excel` because there the leading apostrophe will automatically interpreted as quote prefix. But in a `*.xls` or `*.xlsx` file this automatic will not work properly in all cases. So there we need really setting `CellFormat.QuotePrefix Property` as `Excel` would do after typing a leading apostrophe to cell content in editor bar.

This can be done using `apache poi` by creating a [CellStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html) which has set [setQuotePrefixed(true)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setQuotePrefixed-boolean-).