# Excel / Apache POI: How to escape strings for Excel cells?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to generate XLSX files as reports for customers, with the raw data coming from our system.

I'm facing the issue that I cannnot simply call `setCellValue(myText)` because the variable `myText` may contain characters which need to be escaped for excel. For example:

- strings which start with `=` are interpreted as formulas
- strings containing `'` somewhere in the text are interpreted as validation constraints (which is weird)
- ...

In summary, I need a way to write the content of `myText` into a cell, regardless of any special Excel "magic". I always need the content of the resulting cell to be a text, it should never end up as a formula (also, I need to prevent "formula injection"). So I need to escape the string content somehow. The important thing is: I do not control the content of the input string - it can be literally anything.

Is there some standard escaping method for Excel? I'm working with the Apache POI library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53755866/3094906), that no "escaping" in the traditional sense is necessary.

Using `cell.getCellStyle().setQuotePrefixed(true)` solves the issue.